# In Delphi 7, get a bitmap from a form when the form is higher than the screen

Tags: delphi, bitmap, clipboard

I have a form that is higher than the screen, and when I try to simulate the printscreen key with

```
keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0);
```

of course, the form gets cropped.
So I tried to do the following on the active form:

```
Clipboard.Assign(GetFormImage);
```

but still, even in this case, the bitmap gets cropped too.

There was an old Delphi component, BDPrint, that was available here:

```
http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Printing/
```

but it's not available anymore, that was able to print a form creating a temporary tImage and then printing it, even the off screen portion, but I do not have the source code of it anymore.

How can I generate a bitmap of the active form, with the off screen portion too, and store it in the clipboard? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I could search around some more if I had the time:

- fist get the handle of the window (with [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499.aspx) or somesuch)
- [GetwindowDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144947.aspx)
- [BitBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370.aspx) onto a TBitmap's Canvas.Handle of your own (or [StretchBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120.aspx) or a personal favorite [PlgBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162804.aspx))

Comment: Thank you for now. I am not too familiar with the internal Windows data structures, but it's time I dig into them :) I will let you know as soon as I try it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to involve the clipboard, or otherwise capture the screen.  Try passing the form's `Handle` property to [`PrintWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869.aspx), or send a [`WM_PRINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145216.aspx) message directly to the Form.  Either one will let you specify an `HDC` (such as the one from the `TBitmap.Canvas.Handle` property) for the window to draw itself onto.

Comment: Would it be possible to update your answer with a short Delphi example of how to  use PrintWindow() or how to send a WM_PRINT message. Thank you.